# PowerBI - Referenced Table Column Slicer Not Filtering Other Referenced Table or Parent Table Visuals

Tags: model, powerbi, relationship, slicers

I have a parent table appended from 2 tables pulled in using API links. For the purpose of data tranformation I have to reference tables and transform data before visualization for some visuals (while others can be built from the parent appended table itself). Now some slicers are directly from columns in parent appended table while others are from the referenced tables. Problem is that all these slicers should filter all the visuals I build (whether from parent table or referenced tables). The slicers are not working on all my visuals. How should I connect all slicers to all visuals.

I tried "edit relationships" but none of the visuals block any of the slicers. I feel it is a 'manage relationships' issue. It is not clear to me on how I can build the relationships between all the tables so that all the slicers work on the visuals.